# Fetching data outside of JVM

Tags: java

I'm curious to know if it's possible to fetch data from other applications to my Java program. I know java is running in a virtual environment, hence JVM and therefore have problems communicating with other applications unless you were to use the Robot class or so forth.

What I would like to do, for starters as educational purposes is to take let's say a music application like Spotify/iTunes, fetch the playlist (text data) and send/display it in a text file. I've tried a few things so far, and the only thing I've come close to is by using the Robot class, opening the application, doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, pasting it in to a text document and so forth but that's more like a macro. I would like to make a java application that would do this automatically. Is that possible in any sense with Java or are you just better off changing languages? I wish to do it with Java though because it's the language I've studied for the past year and what I'm trying to master. (Sorry for the long explanation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to do with Java and the JVM. Any language has the same problems and solutions for this sort of situation.

The thing you need to talk to has to provide you a way to talk to it. You need to talk to it using that way.

Methods include pipes, custom network protocols, SOAP and Restful web services, etc.

Comment: I see, what I've been told though is that because java works in the way it works it's not a good language to communicate with other applications. At least not with the same ease as perhaps C++. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Java is not good for writing things like device drivers - since they need direct access to the hardware which is made slower and much harder by the JVM. That's accessing hardware though, not accessing other software. For accessing other software there is no difference between C++ and Java, if anything Java makes it easier.

Answer (score 2):

Just because an application runs in a virtual machine doesn't mean it cannot access external data through an API provided by an external program. For example, iTunes has a [COM-based API for accessing playlists](http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/interfaceIITLibraryPlaylist.html), and here is an example of [using it from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12369/Accessing-songs-and-playlists-from-ITunes-using-C). You'll need something which allows [accessing COM objects from Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom/).

(Please note I know nothing about this topic, this is just what I found with a little searching...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which data interfaces provides the application you want to connect to.

As an example, maybe the application writes files to disk or stores some info in a database.

Then with Java you can read files, query the database, use an API (web services, REST, etc..) and so on...